# nodemon ignore is not working using package.json

Tags: node.js

I am trying to write files in `mails_files` folder using nodejs and I don't want to restart server automatically during the changes in `mails_files` folder for that I have put a following code in my package, json but, nodemon ignore is not working using package.json

**My package.json:**

```
"nodemonConfig": {
    "verbose": true,
    "ignore": ["public","mails_files","logs"]
  }
```

Comment: Hello, please introduce yourself to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and correct your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
"ignore": ["public/*","mails_files/*","logs/*"]
```